# Simultaneous Equations....

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Trying to solve Simultaneous Equations. Homework revision for an exam...
These are rather easy types of simultaneous equations but when revising I found this one and i cant seem to solve it...
$$19s+12t=82 \tag{1}$$
$$5s+4t=30\tag{2}$$

The point of the exercise is to find the values of t and s.

-So what I've done is label the first equation 1 and the second equation 2, as normal.

-Then I multiplied equation 2 by 3 to make the value of t the same on both equations and labelled this, new equation, equation 3:
$$15s+12t=90 \tag{3}$$

-Then I took equation 3 from equation 2 to breaking it down to find the value of s.

**(3)** - **(2)**

$$4s=8$$
$$s=2$$

-So, at this point I have worked out that s=2.

-The problem, for me, is when I substitute the value of s back into equation 1. the value of t is a recurring number of 6.

-Have i done something wrong?

Comment: When you multiplied equation (2) by 3, the right-hand-side is wrong. 3*30=90 not 82. Then you should have done (1) - (3) to get 4s=-8

Comment: Oh sorry thats a mistake. I confused it with the other equation.

Comment: Your last step should have been (1) - (3) to give 4s=-8

Answer (score 1):

$4s=-8$

$s=-2$

Put value in equation (1) or (2)

$t=10$